# How to set Html.fromHtml to SingleChoiceItems?

Tags: android

I'm trying to apply Html tags to an AlertDialog -> setSingleChoiceItems();

I was searching for answers but nothing found.

My example code;

```
final String ex[] = {
    "<small>Some text</small>\n<b>text</b>",
    "<small>Some text</small>\n<b>text</b>",
    "<small>Some text</small>\n<b>text</b>"
};

AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

dialog.setTitle("My dialog");
dialog.setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
dialog.setSingleChoiceItems(ex, 0, null);

dialog.show();
```

How can i apply the html tags and show them on the list?

I try with Html.fromHtml in the String Array but it sais is non compatible types.

Any help?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setSingleChoiceItems` accepts an array of `CharSequence`, from which bot `String` and `Spannable` inherit. This should do it

```
final CharSequence ex[] = {
       Html.fromHtml("<small>Some text</small>\n<b>text</b>"),
       Html.fromHtml("<small>Some text</small>\n<b>text</b>"),
       Html.fromHtml("<small>Some text</small>\n<b>text</b>")
};
```